Implementation of Array.prototype.toLocaleString
I'm interested in the following piece of code written in JS:
const array = [1,2,3];
const locales = 'en-US';
const options = null;
console.log(array.toLocaleString(locales,options));

Before Node.js 20, this would output 1,2,3. However, in Node.js 20, it now throws the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Number.prototype.toLocaleString called on null or undefined
    at Number.toLocaleString (<anonymous>)
    at Array.toLocaleString (<anonymous>)

I'm trying to understand what changed in the implementation. Specifically, I’m looking for the exact line of code that was changed in the source code. I reviewed the ECMAScript language specification but couldn't find any related changes. My focus is on identifying where the code changed in the implementation, rather than understanding the reasoning behind it. Please point me to the right direction.
The reason for this question is because I have a library that introduced a new data structure and provides similar methods as array. I want my DS and the array to have same results for any kind of input, including for null. Once I noticed that between versions, toLocaleString provides a different result, I understood that I need to update my own toLocaleString to support the latest changes. In order to do so, I'm trying to find out the exact change in order to see in my own eyes the change.

what result do you expect?

Why were you ever passing null? [1, 2, 3].toLocaleString("en-US") is fine in Node 20.

@NinaScholz Both 1,2,3 and the exception are valid results. I'm learning about PLs so I'm interested in the source code (implementation) itself. @jonrsharpe I added explanation in the original post for why I want to include null.

Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. The second argument is supposed to be an object, or undefined would explicitly indicate it's missing. null can do anything or nothing or error (for example Firefox gives Uncaught TypeError: can't convert null to object).

"I’m looking for the exact line of code in the source code" - have a go at https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/builtins/array-join.tq. You'll need to find out which versions of V8 node uses, then compare those.

@jonrsharpe there is noch such thing as undefined behaviour in ES262/402 - V8 was simply not spec compliant before.

An error is also thrown in modern Chrome browsers. The options parameter is expected to be object|undefined. The passing of a null to an optional object parameter is not legal.
I believe that V8 is moving away from null treated as undefined, because it does not work very well with the TypeScript language.
Argument
In the TypeScript code below, you can see the TS2345 error. In TypeScript an optional argument ? is interpreted as that type or undefined.
const aNumber: number = 42;
aNumber.toLocaleString("en-US", null);
//                              ----
//                              ^
//                              | Argument of type 'null' is not assignable
//                              | to parameter of type 
//                              | 'NumberFormatOptions | undefined'.
//                              | (2345)


Here is the TypeScript type signature for the Number.prototype.toLocaleString method for reference:
(method) Number.toLocaleString(
  locales?: string | string[],
  options?: Intl.NumberFormatOptions
): string

V8 Code
In reference to option-utils.cc, here is the GetOptionsObject function that checks if the incoming options is undefined or an object. If it is neither, an error is thrown.
See: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/option-utils.cc#L28
// ecma402/#sec-getoptionsobject
MaybeHandle<JSReceiver> GetOptionsObject(Isolate* isolate,
                                         Handle<Object> options,
                                         const char* method_name) {
  // 1. If options is undefined, then
  if (options->IsUndefined(isolate)) {
    // a. Return ! ObjectCreate(null).
    return isolate->factory()->NewJSObjectWithNullProto();
  }
  // 2. If Type(options) is Object, then
  if (options->IsJSReceiver()) {
    // a. Return options.
    return Handle<JSReceiver>::cast(options);
  }
  // 3. Throw a TypeError exception.
  THROW_NEW_ERROR(isolate, NewTypeError(MessageTemplate::kInvalidArgument),
                  JSReceiver);
}

Here is the specification that the code is adhering to:
See: https://402.ecma-international.org/11.0/index.html#sec-getoptionsobject

9.2.8 GetOptionsObject ( options )
The abstract operation GetOptionsObject takes argument options (an ECMAScript language value) and returns either a normal completion containing an Object or a throw completion. It returns an Object suitable for use with GetOption, either options itself or a default empty Object. It throws a TypeError if options is not undefined and not an Object. It performs the following steps when called:

If options is undefined, then

Return OrdinaryObjectCreate(null).


If Type(options) is Object, then

Return options.


Throw a TypeError exception. <--- HERE



"V8 is moving away from null treated as undefined, because it does not work very well with the TypeScript language" - that doesn't make sense to me, V8 doesn't use TypeScript? +1 on the rest though

Yeah, TypeScript has nothing to do with it, it was a fix for a spec deviation: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/v8/v8/+/4184564

If that's the reason, the error message is rather confusing imo. "Number.prototype.toLocaleString called on null or undefined" sounds like it was called without a receiver, i.e. toLocaleString.call(null, …) - it should rather say "was called with …".

I was mentioning TypeScript as an argument for the potential reasoning.
